# When would I pass const& std::string instead of std::string_view?

Tags: c++, string, stl, parameter-passing, string-view

I understand the motivation for using [std::string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view);
it can help avoid unecessary allocations in function arguments.

**For example:**
The following program will create a `std::string` from a string literal.
This causes an undesired dynamic allocation, as we are only interested observing the characters.

```
#include <iostream>

void* operator new(std::size_t n)
{
    std::cout << "[allocating " << n << " bytes]\n";
    return malloc(n);
}

void observe_string(std::string const& str){}

int main(){
  observe_string("hello world"); //prints [allocating 36 bytes]
}
```

Using `string_view` will solve the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/string_view>

void* operator new(std::size_t n)
{
    std::cout << "[allocating " << n << " bytes]\n";
    return malloc(n);
}

void observe_string(std::experimental::string_view const& str){
}

int main(){
  observe_string("hello world"); //prints nothing
}
```

---

This leaves me with a question.
**When would I choose std::string by const& instead of string_view for function arguments?**

Looking at the interface of `std::string_view`, it looks as though I could replace all instances of `std::string` that are passed by `const&`.  Are there any counter examples to this?  Is `std::string_view` meant to replace `std::string const&` for parameter passing?

Comment: I was going to say: if the function was going to stash away the parameter into a discrete std::string internally, then copy-construction would be cheaper than string-to-string-view-to-string round-trip. But I realized that basic_string_view could memorize that it was constructed from a string, and just return the same one from its to_string() method.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: If you're gonna make a copy, you want to accept the argument by value so it can be either copy- or move-constructed.

Comment: If you're going to pass the parameter along to something that only takes a string, such as `ifstream`'s constructor or `operator+` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636549/why-is-there-no-support-for-concatenating-stdstring-and-stdstring-view)) then you might as well take it as a `const string &`. (I suppose this is just a complicated way of saying "When you really need a `string`.)

Answer (score 23):

> When would I choose `std::string` by `const&` instead of `string_view` for function arguments?

Do you *need* a null-terminated string? If so, then you should use `std::string const&` which gives you that guarantee. `string_view` does not - it's simply a range of `const char`.

If you *do not* need a null-terminated string, and you do not need to take ownership of the data, then you should use `string_view`. If you do need to take ownership of the data, then it may be the case that `string` by value is better than `string_view`.

Comment: For clarification: needing my string null-terminated means that the `std::string` underlying `char`-array should end in `\0`, right? Hard to imagine someone needs this when using `std::string` already. Its like mixing C with modern C++, or am I wrong?

Comment: If one needs a NTBS, I think they may just use `const char*` as the parameter type.

Comment: @M.Winter It's pretty easy to imagine... there's plenty of APIs that require null-terminated strings.

Comment: Yes an issue as many things use std::string::c_str() and assume it will be "nul terminated"

Comment: @peterk Hm? `std::string::c_str` *is* null terminated.

Answer (score 11):

One possible reason to accept `const std::string&` instead of `string_view` is when you want to store reference to string object which can change later.

If you accept and store a `string_view`, it might become invalid when `string` internal buffer reallocates.

If you accept and store reference to string itself, you won't have that problem, as long as that object is alive (you probably want to delete r-value reference overload, to avoid obvious problem with temporaries).

Answer (score 4):

Andrei Alexandrescu once said, *"No Work is better than some work"*. So you should use `const std::string&` in such contexts. Because `std::string_view` still involves some work (copying a pair of pointer and length).

Of course, const references may still have the cost of copying a pointer; which is almost the equivalent of what `std::string_view` will do. But there's one additional work with `std::string_view`, it also copies the length.

*This is in theory, but in practice, a benchmark will be preferred to infer performance*

---

Comment: If the function is called with a string literal, the `const string&` version will do more work.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but a for a string_view it would be two pointers, or a pointer and a length. So the work would be exactly double. More important to consider is whether or not 16 bytes will fit in your CPU registers along with any other arguments (as opposed to 8 bytes for a single pointer); and, as @juanchopanza said, all the times users will end up with a scan of their string.

Answer (score 3):

It is not really what you were asking, but sometimes you want to take `std::string` *by value* rather than `std::string_view` for performance reasons. This is the case when you will need to modify the string before inspecting it:

```
bool matches(std::string s)
{
  make_upper_case(s);
  return lib::test_if_matches(s);
}
```

You need a mutable string somewhere anyway, so you may declare it as function parameter. If you changed it to to `std::string_view`, and somebody passes an `std::string` to function `matches()` you would be first converting `string` to `string_view` and then `string_view` to `string`, and therefore allocating twice.