# Why is there no support for concatenating std::string and std::string_view?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

Since C++17, we have [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), a light-weight view into a contiguous sequence of characters that avoids unnecessary copying of data. Instead of having a `const std::string&` parameter, it is now often recommended to use `std::string_view`.

However, one quickly finds out that switching from `const std::string&` to `std::string_view` breaks code that uses string concatenation as there is no support for concatenating `std::string` and `std::string_view`:

```
std::string{"abc"} + std::string_view{"def"}; // ill-formed (fails to compile)
std::string_view{"abc"} + std::string{"def"}; // ill-formed (fails to compile)
```

Why is there no support for concatenating `std::string` and `std::string_view` in the standard?

Comment: Most likely an oversight.  That said, it doesn't take much to add a `operator +` to make the code work.

Comment: Just found this: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/1RcShRhrmRc

Comment: What I also miss is a member function of std::basic_string that returns the std::basic_string_view of a sub-string (similar to the "substr" member function), perhaps named "substr_view".

Comment: have a look at this. https://github.com/OlafvdSpek/xbt/blob/master/misc/xbt/string_view.h

Comment: @NathanOliver Doing that would conflict with a possible future addition of this operator to the language, so it is not recommended.

Comment: its also not possible to add two `std::string_view`s
`error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view<char>'} and 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view<char>'})`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The reason for this is given in [n3512 string_ref: a non-owning reference to a string, revision 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3512.html) by Jeffrey Yasskin:

> I also omitted operator+(basic_string, basic_string_ref) because LLVM returns a lightweight object from this overload and only performs the concatenation lazily. If we define this overload, we'll have a hard time introducing that lightweight concatenation later.

It has been later suggested on the [std-proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/1RcShRhrmRc) mailing list to add these operator overloads to the standard. There is also a paper to add them: [P2591 Concatenation of strings and string views](https://wg21.link/p2591).

Comment: Wow. Just wow! This seems to be the *worst* possible reason for leaving something out. The standard is supposed to be for the good of the *language,* not for any particular implementation. I'm also wary of the "performs the concatenation lazily" - does this mean that, should we have a memory shortage, the exception for adding to the original string will *also* be deferred? I sure as hell hope not, I want to know if an operation fails when *I* do it, not ten minutes later when I access the result.

Comment: Hopefully someone submit's a proposal to include these operators.

Comment: In the [fmtlib/fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library works great with `string_view`.

Comment: [`std::basic_string::append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) has an overload that accepts everything that can be implicitly converted to a `std::string_view`. Of course this is not the same as `operator+()`.

Comment: What alternatives do the commentators here do suggest if one needs an efficient c++ string concatenation(i.e. string builder)? For example, c# libraries has an efficient uri_builder class, which takes a group of strings and creates one by using a to_string() method; which in affect could be realized if string_view were to have a +() overload.

Comment: my_s.insert(0, my_sv); // s = sv + s  
my_s.append(my_sv);  // s = s + sv

Comment: @b.g.: There's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462951/c-equivalent-of-stringbuffer-stringbuilder) for that.

Comment: As a workaround, you can also call `string_object + string_view_object.data()`. This actually calls the `operator+()` overload that takes a `const char*`, but that works and should be efficient

Comment: @joesdiner That is NOT safe, `data` is not null-terminated and `const char*`-taking overload expects it to be.

Comment: is there an official proposal for this yet?

Comment: This is _especially_ glaring when compared to [std::basic_string::operator+=()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), which has taken `string_view`-likes of all sorts since `basic_string_view` was introduced.  The cleanest equivalent to adding `string_view sv`s to `string s`s is literally `s + ""s.operator+=(sv)`, and I'm not even sure how safe that is.

Comment: (In the sense of actually performing concatenation between `string` and `string_view` specifically.  Strictly speaking, creating a string from `sv`, so you could add `s + std::string(sv)`, is cleaner and more performant, but that concatenates two strings.  `""s.operator+=(sv)` does string concatenation, too, but it _does_ at least concatenate `sv` to a temporary string in the process.  This is mainly an illustrative point to highlight the issue, not actual code I'd expect to see somewhere.)

Answer (score 29):

I've submitted [P2591: Concatenation of strings and string views](https://wg21.link/p2591), linking to this SO question. The paper at this point is targeted at C++26 minimum.

Comment: This probably isn't where critique of the proposal should go, but I noticed that your example code has `view` as an `std::string`, not as an `std::string_view`.

Comment: Hi! Yes, duly noted; I've already fixed that and another couple of typos in an upcoming revision.

Comment: Will P2591 allow all of these?
1: sv + sv
2: sv + std::string
3: sv + string literal (const char*)
4: sv + character literal (char)

Comment: No, that's out of scope (in scope for a string builder, perhaps). Just kickstart the chain with a conversion to `string`, then keep chaining. (IOW, those opreations need to allocate memory; hence you need an allocator; but none of those operations let you specify one)

Comment: C++26?... Mind blown. IMHO this should be considered a defect and applied retroactively to C++17.