# Why not make { "hello"s + "world"sv; } valid in C++20?

Tags: c++, string, standards, c++20, library-design

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    "hello"s + "world";   // ok
    "hello"s + "world"sv; // error
}
```

See online [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/49oov96ja)

**Why not make** `"hello"s + "world"sv` **valid in C++20?**

Comment: Because C++20 has already been published, and new changes cannot be made anymore.

Comment: `std::string_view` is of C++17, why did C++20 still not provide such an overloaded operator? Just an oversight?

Comment: Either 1. It was proposed and rejected or 2. It wasn't proposed. Read through the proposals to find out which it was.

Comment: [Why is there no support for concatenating `std::string` and `std::string_view`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44636549/995714)

Comment: The reasoning isn’t any different one language version later, even including the possibility that “no one got around to it yet”.