# Concatenating string_view objects

Tags: c++, c++17, string-concatenation, string-view

I've been adding `std::string_view`s to some old code for representing string like config params, as it provides a read only view, which is faster due to no need for copying.

However, one cannot concatenate two `string_view` together as the `operator+` isn't defined. I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44636549/3021102) has a couple answers stating its an oversight and there is a proposal in for adding that in. However, that is for adding a `string` and a `string_view`, presumably if that gets implemented, the resulting concatenation would be a `std::string`

Would adding two `string_view` also fall in the same category? And if not, why shouldn't adding two `string_view` be supported?

Sample

```
std::string_view s1{"concate"};
std::string_view s2{"nate"};
std::string_view s3{s1 + s2};
```

And here's the error

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view<char>'} and 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view<char>'})
```

Comment: A `string_view` does not _own_ the data. It must be stored somewhere. For concatenating, use a `std::string`.

Comment: The "oversight" mentioned in the other question is the oversight of adding a string_view to a string, and not adding two string_views together.  There's no proposal to implement like this for the simple reason that it's logically impossible to do anything like this, for fundamental reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `std::string_view` is an alias for `std::basic_string_view<char>`, which is a `std::basic_string_view` templated on a specific type of character, i.e. `char`.

But what does it look like?

Beside the fairly large number of useful member functions such as `find`, `substr`, and others (maybe it's an ordinary number, if compared to other container/string-like things offered by the STL), `std::basic_string_view<_CharT>`, with `_CharT` being the generic `char`-like type, has just 2 data members,

```cpp
// directly from my /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/string_view
      size_t        _M_len;
      const _CharT* _M_str;
```

i.e. a `const`ant pointer to `_CharT` to indicate where the view starts, and a `size_t` (an appropriate type of number) to indicate how long the view is starting from `_M_str`'s pointee.

In other words, a string view just knows where it starts and how long it is, so it represents a sequence of `char`-like entities which are **consecutive in memory**. With just two such members, you can't represent a string which is made up of non-contiguous substrings.

Yet in other words, if you want to create a `std::string_view`, you need to be able to tell how many `char`s it is long and from which position. Can you tell where `s1 + s2` would have to start and how many characters it should be long? Think about it: you can't, becase `s1` and `s2` are not adjacent.

Maybe a diagram can help.

Assume these lines of code

```cpp
std::string s1{"hello"};
std::string s2{"world"};
```

`s1` and `s2` are totally unrelated objects, as far as their memory location is concerned; here is what they looks like:

```
                           &s2[0]
                             |
                             | &s2[1]
                             |   |
&s1[0]                       |   | &s2[2]
  |                          |   |   |
  | &s1[1]                   |   |   | &s2[3]
  |   |                      |   |   |   |
  |   | &s1[2]               |   |   |   | &s2[4]
  |   |   |                  |   |   |   |   |
  |   |   | &s1[3]           v   v   v   v   v
  |   |   |   |            +---+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   |   | &s1[4]     | w | o | r | l | d |
  |   |   |   |   |        +---+---+---+---+---+
  v   v   v   v   v
+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I've intentionally drawn them misaligned to mean that `&s1[0]`, the memory location where `s1` starts, and `&s2[0]`, the memory location where `s2` starts, have nothing to do with each other.

Now, imagine you create two string views like this:

```cpp
std::string_view sv1{s1};
std::string_view sv2(s2.begin() + 1, s2.begin() + 4);
```

Here's what they will look like, in terms of the two implementation-defined members `_M_str` and `_M_len`:

```
                                &s2[0]
                                  |
                                  | &s2[1]
                                  |   |
     &s1[0]                       |   | &s2[2]
       |                          |   |   |
       | &s1[1]                   |   |   | &s2[3]
       |   |                      |   |   |   |
       |   | &s1[2]               |   |   |   | &s2[4]
       |   |   |                  |   |   |   |   |
       |   |   | &s1[3]           v   v   v   v   v
       |   |   |   |            +---+---+---+---+---+
       |   |   |   | &s1[4]     | w | o | r | l | d |
       |   |   |   |   |        +---+---+---+---+---+
       v   v   v   v   v            · ^         ·
     +---+---+---+---+---+          · |         ·
     | h | e | l | l | o |        +---+         ·
     +---+---+---+---+---+        | ·           ·
     · ^                 ·        | · s2._M_len ·
     · |                 ·        | <----------->
   +---+                 ·        |
   | ·                   ·        +-- s2._M_str
   | ·       s1._M_len   ·
   | <------------------->
   |
   +-------- s1._M_str
```

Given the above, can you see what's wrong with expecting that

```cpp
std::string_view s3{s1 + s2};
```

works?

How can you possible define `s3._M_str` and `s3._M_len` (based on `s1._M_str`, `s1._M_len`, `s2._M_str`, and `s2._M_len`), such that they represent a view on `"helloworld"`?

You can't because `"hello"` and `"world"` are located in two unrelated areas of memory.

Comment: While this makes sense, it does not explain why you cannot concatenate a `string` and a `string_view` and get a `string`. Maybe the intention behind not allowing this is that it would be unclear if the intention is to produce a concatenated view (as with `std::views::join` in C++20, which is NOT a `string_view`, as it is not contiguous), or a new `string`, which holds the concatenated result in its own storage.

Comment: @FlorianWinter, if by concatenating a `std::string` with a `std::string_view` you mean `a_string + a_string_view`, allowing it would require that `a_string_view` be converted to `std::string` via [the ctor (10)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), but that is `explicit`, so that's not possible.

Comment: Not really, because converting the `string_view` to a `string` would be an unnecessary memory allocation. Concatenating a `string` and a `string_view` should not require more than one memory allocation. In addition, if the `string` is an r-value, then it could be reused, e.g., its storage may already have the needed capacity to hold the result, requiring no memory allocation at all. While it could be implemented this way, I think there was an official reason given why the standard does not support this operation.

Comment: Furthermore, the intention of such a concatenation may vary. The intended result COULD be a `string` with its own storage, but it COULD also be a be a view (but not a `string_view`), which is what `std::views::join` does. Of course, the result of a concatenation cannot be a `string_view` (but it can be a view, in the sense of the C++20 ranges library).

Comment: Somehow I forgot about this conversation. @FlorianWinter, when I wrote _would require that `a_string_view` be converted to `std::string`_ I was referring to the fact `std::string_view` has no `operator+`, and `std::string`'s `operator+` overloads all take `std::string`/`char`/`char const*`, and `std::string_view` is convertible to `std::string`, not to `char const*`. So I guess your curiosity is why doesn't `operator+` have an overload for `(std::string, std::string_view)` and `(std::string_view, std::string)`?

Comment: My two comments were a combination of: (1) Concatenation of any number of strings into a new owning container (regardless of representation of the original strings) should never require more than one memory allocation and (2) The intention of a + operator that concatenates views and owning containers could be unclear, which may be one reason why such an operator does not (and should not?) exist. My previous comments are more detailed. These are just statements/comments. I have no further questions :).

Comment: Another way to see this: `string_view` is a contiguous range of characters. It is therefore inherently not closed under concatenation (but there are functions in the ranges library to concatenate views and get a non-contiguous range). `basic_string`, on the other hand, IS in principle closed under concatenation. It COULD be a convention in the standard that any legal concatenation of any range of characters with a `basic_string` would return a `basic_string` and perform no more than one memory allocation (and reuse the storage of an R-value `basic_string` argument if possible).

Answer (score 13):

A view is similar to a span in that it does not own the data, as the name implies it is just a view of the data. To concatenate the string views you'd first need to construct a `std::string` then you can concatenate.

```
std::string s3 = std::string(s1) + std::string(s2);
```

Note that `s3` will be a `std::string` not a `std::string_view` since it would own this data.

Comment: Alt. `std::string s3 = std::string(s1) += s2;` - I'm assuming it'll do one allocation less if `s2` is not short enough for short string optimization.

Comment: So to store `s3` as a `string_view` I should
`std::string_view s3{std::string(s1) + std::string(s2)};`

Comment: @simplename No, where will the data be stored then? As soon as the `std::string` goes out of scope, any `string_view` you have to it will not be useful anymore. You must store the `std::string`. You can make as many `string_view`s you like to it - but you need to keep it alive.

Comment: @simplename I’ll post this as a full answer if I have the time but if you’re that determined to keep everything as a `sv` for a long as possible you could create a simple class that aggregates the `sv`s. But frankly I wouldn’t worry about that unless you’re absolutely sure this is slowing down your system and that the solution is faster

Answer (score 6):

`std::string_view` does not own any data, it is only a **view**. If you want to join two views to get a joined view, you can use `boost::join()` from the Boost library. But result type will be not a `std::string_view`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>

void test()
{
    std::string_view s1{"hello, "}, s2{"world"};
    auto joined = boost::join(s1, s2);

    // print joined string
    std::copy(joined.begin(), joined.end(), std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, ""));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // other method to print
    for (auto c : joined) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

C++23 has joined ranges in the standard library with the name of `std::ranges::views::join_with_view`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

void test()
{
    std::string_view s1{"hello, "}, s2{"world"};
    auto joined = std::ranges::views::join_with_view(s1, s2);

    for (auto c : joined) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That C++23 code is incorrect, as `join_with_view` is in the `std::ranges` namespace, not `std::ranges::views`.  I get a constraint failure when I fixed that. In any case, we don't want `"world"` _between each character_ of `"hello, "`.  Luckily, there's a simpler C++20 version: `std::views::join(std::array{s1, s2})`.

Comment: I've added my own answer with verified working code.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string_view` is a lightweight, non-owning view of the characters.

To get a view that concatenates multiple string views, we can use the *join* view adapter that was introduced in C++20:

```
    auto const joined = std::views::join(std::array{s1, s2});
```

This gives us a view object that can be iterated over using standard algorithms or range-based `for`.  It can be converted to a `std::string` object (but not directly to a `std::string_view` as that requires us to copy the contents somewhere to make them contiguous).

Full demo:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    const std::string_view s1{"con"};
    const std::string_view s2{"cate"};
    const std::string_view s3{"nate"};

    return !std::ranges::equal(std::views::join(std::array{s1, s2, s3}),
                               std::string_view{"concatenate"});
}
```