# Is there sense in using const std::string& arguments in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

By getting `string_view` in C++17 we got cheap method of passing both `std::string` and `char*` to functions that do not take ownership of the string and avoid making temporary copies. By using `std::string` passed by value and `std::move` we get explicit and fast passing of string ownership for both r-value and l-value references.

My question is: is there any benefit in using `const std::string&` as any function parameter in new C++ standard?

Comment: [How exactly is std::string_view faster than const std::string&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127965), [When would I pass const& std::string instead of std::string_view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564457), [Why only string view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023938), provide various information about that topic. As your question is close to those, you should mention what particular information is missing in those question and their answers.

Comment: In one word: Null-termination.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes.

The problem with `std::string_view` is that it doesn't remember if it points to a null-terminated string or not.

If you're writing a wrapper for a C api that uses null-terminated strings, you would have to constantly copy your `std::string_view`s into `std::string`s to make sure you have null-terminators.

Comment: Exactly. Properly written C++17 code should provide overloads for `const char *`, `const std::string &` and `std::string_view`. Especially since many parts of standard library didn't receive `string_view` support (exceptions, for example).

Comment: @StaceyGirl and here we go again with C++ complexity exploding in the face of the user

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure `std::string_view` is slower if one worries so much about micro-performance. Not like it matters, but it really _ought to be_ slower. Passing a `string const&` will alias the string object which is a pointer in the worst case, and "no op" in the average case. Passing a `string_view` calls `operator string_view` to initialize a NRVO-copied `string_view` which initializes a pointer and a size. When given a `const char*` rather than a `string` it will call `strlen`, so...

Comment: @StaceyGirl Does that mean that many parts of the C++17 standard library, such as exceptions, are not properly written C++17 code?

Comment: @wrtlprnft Standard exceptions didn't receive `string_view` constructors and only have `const char *`/`const std::string &` ones, so if you want to pass a `string_view` from a derived class, you will have to create an additional string copy - something that `string_view` was supposed to avoid while reducing number of overloads.

Comment: does it mean that changing global constants from `const std::string{"..."}` to `const auto{"..."sv}` is always beneficial?

Comment: @NooneAtAll If you don't plan on passing those to functions with `const char *` or `const std::string &` parameters, then string view constants should be better, since they don't require heap allocations at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is about C++17, but in C++20 I think that you can finally avoid using `std::string&` arguments by using C++20's concepts.

You can write a concept that requires that the argument type is convertible to an `std::string_view` and also convertible to either a `const char*` or an `std::string`, thus NULL-terminated. You can then convert the argument to a `string_view` in the function body, and you can safely use that `string_view` in C APIs, without doing runtime checks.

Here's an example from a small [libcurl wrapper](https://github.com/Tachi107/scrafurl/blob/main/include/scrafurl.hpp) I maintain:

```cpp
// NULL-terminated std::string_view
template<typename T>
concept Text = std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view> && (std::convertible_to<T, std::string> || std::convertible_to<T, const char*>);

void get(const std::string_view url, const Text auto... headers) noexcept {
    // ...
    struct curl_slist* curl_headers {nullptr};
    if constexpr (sizeof...(headers) != 0) {
        const std::array header_array {static_cast<std::string_view>(headers)...};
        for (const std::string_view header : header_array) {
            curl_headers = curl_slist_append(curl_headers, header.data());
        }
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, curl_headers);
    // ...
}
```