# When do you need a null terminated string in a read-only scenario?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

I've been playing around with the [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view) library and I have been contemplating on changing a code base I have been working on to use `std::string_view` as much as possible. However, in many of the threads that I have read on the subject of when and where to use `std::string_view` instead of `const std::string &`. I have seen many answers say, "When you don't need a null terminated string." So as I began searching around the web for, "when do you need a null terminated string?" I haven't really come across any helpful answers on the subject.

I can think of an example of an external library that you will link to that requires a `std::string`. And in that case you would need a null terminated string since that library requires it. I guess another example would be if you need to modify the string  itself, but then we wouldn't pass it by `const &` if we needed to modify it.

So when would you need to use a null terminated string?

Links that I have looked at:

1. [How exactly is std::string_view faster than const std::string&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127965/how-exactly-is-stdstring-view-faster-than-const-stdstring)
2. [When would I pass const& std::string instead of std::string_view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564457/when-would-i-pass-const-stdstring-instead-of-stdstring-view)
3. [Why only string view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023938/why-only-string-view)
4. [Is there sense in using const std::string& arguments in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951871/is-there-sense-in-using-const-stdstring-arguments-in-c17?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: To interface with C APIs, mostly.

Comment: @uneven_mark can you provide an example of one?

Comment: The accepted answer to the fourth question you link seems like it answers this question.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Most functions from e.g. POSIX or any other C library taking a `const char*` argument. eerorika's anwer has an example.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so really the answer is, "As long as the API doesn't call for a null terminated string?"

Comment: It would be a mistake to standardise on string_view. You don't know when you will need to communicate with an external interface in future. If that happens, you will be forced to make a copy of the string which will eradicate any perceived gains in performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When do you need a null terminated string?

You need a null terminated string whenever the API that you use says that you need it. This requirement is ubiquitous in C interfaces and not explicitly stated in some documentation. If a function argument is a `char*` (possibly to const), and there is no length argument, you should assume the requirement unless documentation says otherwise.

Let's take the function `execve` (from POSIX standard) as an example:

```
int execve(const char *pathname, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

If you pass a non-null terminated argument as `pathname`, then the behaviour of your program will be undefined.

Comment: So in this case, the pathname, were it to be a `std::string`, would be executed like `execve(pathname.c_str(),...,...)`?

Answer (score 6):

It's actually pretty easy to know.  If you are calling a function that just takes a c-string (`char*`/`const char*`), then you need a null terminated string as that is the only way to know where then end of the string is.

If you instead have a function that takes a `char*`/`const char*` plus the size, or just two pointers marking the beginning and end of the data, then you don't need a null terminated string since you have/can get the string size without iterating to a null terminator.